# android debug apk crashing but release apk run successfully

Tags: android, android-studio

While running apk from android studio via adb it is working/running properly. but when i am giving that debug apk to my client it is crashing. but when i am giving signed apk it is working fine.

The debug apk installed successfully but when it going to run then it get "class not found error".

```
09-19 20:05:12.065 29019-29019/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.volansys.homebridge, PID: 29019
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.volansys.homebridge.HomeBridgeApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.volansys.homebridge.HomeBridgeApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.volansys.homebridge-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.volansys.homebridge-2/lib/arm, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
   at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:802)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5376)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1541)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.volansys.homebridge.HomeBridgeApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.volansys.homebridge-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.volansys.homebridge-2/lib/arm, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1014)
   at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:796)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5376) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1541) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

i also changed the manifest file and gave the whole path to the application class like

> android:name="package_name.HomeBridgeApplication"

When i going to ctrl+click on this class it can navigate to this class. it means path is proper so why i am getting class not found error ?

can anyone help me ? 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I have seen this error a lot lately, I have 2 clues. Maybe is Windows and maybe is the compile. Can you please tell me the OS and the SDK level used?

Comment: Are you using Multidex?

Comment: Yes I am using Multidex

Comment: OS is Ubuntu 14.04 and   minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24

Comment: When I disable the Instant Run then its working